# How to check that the image was changed if there're no changes in HTML code?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, kotlin, selenide

How to check that the image was changed if there're no changes in HTML code? It may sound a little bit complicated so I'll try to add some details.

First of all, I write tests with Kotlin + Selenide but if your tips\tricks\answers will be in Java + Selenium I'm totally OK.

Secondly, here's the situation: 
I have a visualizer of user's future kitchen where he\she can add\edit\delete different stuff, e.g. sinks and faucets. 
There're several presets: some of them with cabinets, some of them have tables, tables with chairs, etc. 
It is coded like this: `<a href="#" class="preset-buttons-selected" style="background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/bla-bla-bla/some_image.png");"></a>`

So, when the user changes something, e.g. adds a Sink, image is actually changed, but nothing is changed in the html code that is why I **CANNOT** verify the changes in the autotests. 
I see that there're new images were pulled from [s3.amazonaws.com](http://s3.amazonaws.com) but it is only visible in Network tab of the browser console and it is not visible in the html code of the page.

So, my question is, can I somehow verify that changes in my UI automation tests?

Comment: Have you considered using screenshots?  Selenium can take screenshots, you can take a before and after screenshot and compare the images.

Comment: Is there any change in the DOM apart from the static image details after adding a sink?

Comment: @Taylor, yes, it is possible but that will add manual work to my autotests :)

Comment: @santhoshkumar, no, nothing is changed

Comment: @Viterzgir you can programmatically compare the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was to get a hash of the image before and after the changes and then see if the hash is the same. This will tell you if the image has changed.

Here's a quick example and a function that you can use in your code.

This function takes in a `URL` to the image and returns the MD5 hash of that image.

```
public static String getHashOfImage(URL imageUrl) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    BufferedImage buffImg = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(buffImg, "png", outputStream);
    byte[] data = outputStream.toByteArray();

    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md5.update(data);
    byte[] digest = md5.digest();

    return new BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16);
}
```

and here's a quick example using a test site that contains three random images. You should see a hash printed for each of the three images. Each time you load the page, a different set of three images are loaded but if you run it a few times you should get an instance where two are the same so you can verify that the hash is indeed the same when two images are the same.

```
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dynamic_content");

List<WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img"));
for (int i = 1; i < images.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(getHashOfImage(new URL(images.get(i).getAttribute("src"))));
}
```

Example output would look like

```
c8977e445530e09a06ce368f7f5e70dd
c8977e445530e09a06ce368f7f5e70dd
62baf598cd68eec5725df67e33c05cba
```

where the first two images were the same but different from the third.

Some of this code was adapted from https://sites.google.com/site/matthewjoneswebsite/java/md5-hash-of-an-image